# How to insert html code MediumEditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, medium-editor

My code

```
var care =  MediumEditor.selection.getSelectionStart(editor.options.ownerDocument);
care.after("<b>hi</b>");
```

return

```
&lt;b&gt;hi&lt;/b&gt;
```

you need

**hi**

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/blob/master/API.md#pastehtmlhtml-options), use `editor.pasteHtml('<b>hi</b>');` This will paste the html code at the cursor or selection.

Answer (score 0):

The `after()` function is returning a string where `<` and `>` are represented as `&lt;` and `&gt;`. One simple solution would be to replace those strings with their respective symbols, like so:

```js
var after = '&lt;b&gt;hi&lt;/b&gt;';

var html = after
  .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
  .replace(/&gt;/g, '>');

document.write(html);
```

I am using [String's replace() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).